# How to divide a page equally into left and right in css?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I need to equally divide the entire page to 2 parts as left and right and make the content aligned vertically in left and right sections. Means the image and the text should be end in same point and aligned in a same vertical line. How can I create a resposive layout like this?
To be more specific, I need to do what has [etoro.com](https://etoro.com) done.
[This is the layout I'm gonna achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic2t2.jpg)

Comment: You can use a CSS grid. If you want to learn more about CSS grid you can learn at CSS tricks or MDN.

Comment: https://web.dev/learn/css/grid/ CSS Guide from Google. Best in the world. Period. Every Modern Layout in CSS is done with `display: grid;`. You should learn it :)

Answer (score 1):

With CSS, you can create grids:

Here is a little example:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 50px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div> 
</div>
```

Here is some documentation from w3schools. Hope this helps: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex` for page layout:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.left,
.right {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  border: solid;
}

.content {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .left,
  .right {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg">
    <div class="content">This is left div.This is left div.This is left div.This is left div.This is left div.This is left div.This is left div.This is left div.This is left div.This is left div.This is left div.This is left div.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="content">This is right div.This is right div.This is right div.This is right div.This is right div.This is right div.This is right div.This is right div.This is right div.This is right div.This is right div.</div>
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have used flex. But when we add flex containers, They are not equally aligned to one side.

Comment: @VinudPerera I do not understand what you mean! see the result of 'Run code snippet'. They are equal. I now added borders to flex items that you see equaling of them.

Answer (score 0):

One method you might choose to implement is CSS column logic.

Using the the table and tr tags you can create rows within each column to store individual elements.

Your left and right halves of the screen you will use column divs, and internally for each item you use a tr div like so:

```css
.container
{
    float:center;
}

.column
{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.element
{
    border: 3px solid green;
    margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="column">
        <h1 style="text-align:center;">Column #1</h1>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <div class="element">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin sodales est et posuere dapibus.</p>
            </div>
          </tr>
          
          <tr>
            <div class="element">
              <p>Morbi in felis sit amet quam congue bibendum. </p>
            </div>
          </tr>
          
          <tr>
             <div class="element">
              <p>Nullam suscipit elit blandit, sagittis ligula ac, iaculis magna.</p>
            </div>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <h1 style="text-align:center;">Column #2</h1>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <div class="element">
              <p>Curabitur magna lectus, scelerisque vitae velit a, auctor gravida ex.</p>
            </div>
          </tr>
          
          <tr>
            <div class="element">
              <p>Donec erat quam, iaculis vitae orci id, aliquam pretium ante.</p>
            </div>
          </tr>
          
          <tr>
             <div class="element">
              <p>Praesent quis libero malesuada arcu iaculis cursus.</p>
            </div>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I need to equally aligned the contents vertically.